# Evidence of Applicant's Travel History for Visitor Visa (600) Australia

Tags: paperwork, australia, applications

I am stuck in progressing the visitor visa profile of my parents as it is not letting me go to next step. 
My parents have never travelled overseas yet and they have no history of travel. The online application is not progressing further because it says I have to attach required documents for this " Evidence of Applicant's travel history."

Not sure What should I attach , Please help

Comment: What did you enter for previous travel history? I’m not familiar with the application form but isn’t there a ‘None’ or equivalent option that would mean the request for documents doesn’t appear or doesn’t need to be completed?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold

Comment: I face the same issue. The form had question as to whether the applicant had a previous travel history. But, whichever answer is given (e.g. not travelled before), the documents to be attached include 'Evidence for previous travel' and the application cannot be submitted without submitting a file in this category.

Comment: what did you do? how did you fix this?